# How to forward call to different number if first connect call to number is busy or not responding in Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-studio, twilio-taskrouter

In Twilio Studio, I have a flow which connects call to non-twilio number in the end.
This number can be busy as I am forwarding all incoming requests to this number.

If this currently forwarded number is busy or operator does not respond then I want to connect that call to a different number.

How can we do this in Twilio Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this blog and in particular, `DialCallStatus`, to determine call disposition. Based on the value after the `Connect Call To` Widget, you can decide the next steps (if the call connected or it was `busy` or `no-answer`.

[Build Voice Mail with SMS and Email Notifications Using Twilio Studio, Functions, and SendGrid](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-serverless-voice-mail-sms-email-forwarding)

[image]